# beamer + noto + listings + \ttfamily: Curly Brackets Not Displayed Correctly

Tags: beamer, fonts, listings, noto

- I am using `beamer` together with the `noto` fonts.
- I am finally done with my slide deck and wanted to ass a `listings` with some `biblatex` information.
- The problem is that some characters, e.g. `{` are not displayed correctly. When I remove the `noto` package then the problem disappears but I want to keep the `noto` package.

Any ideas?

---

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{listings}

% Comment out and it works.
\usepackage{noto}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{\insertsectionhead{}}

If you are using \LaTeX\ in combination with the \texttt{biblatex} package, then please consider the following information.
\begin{lstlisting}[
    % Options
    basicstyle = \ttfamily\small,
    breaklines = true,
    numbers = left,
]
@unpublished{Kuehner2022,
    author = {Manuel Kuehner},
    title = {Joule or Newton, That is the Question},
    subtitle = {The Benefits of Mechanical Control Elements in Automotive User Interfaces},
    eventdate = {2022-12-07/2022-12-08},
    url = {https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Manuel-Kuehner},
    howpublished = {Slide Deck of a Conference Talk},
    eventtitle = {Smart Haptics},
    location = {Seattle, Washington, USA},
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update

Boiling the MWE down shows that `basicstyle = \ttfamily` seems to be the core of the issue.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{noto}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{lstlisting}[
    % Options
    basicstyle = \ttfamily
]
{}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` fixes the issue.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks! I was (wrongly) assuming that that is not needed anymore with current LaTeX versions.

Comment: @MarijnPlease provide an answer and I will accept.

Comment: No that's `inputenc` :) usually when wrong characters show up you should use T1 font encoding. Of course in this case another solution would be to use the OpenType Noto fonts with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and `fontspec`.

Comment: We have a lot of questions about mixed up characters where `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is the solution, let me see if I can find one to close as a duplicate.

Comment: This canonical looks ok, your case falls under the third bullet point of the accepted answer I think.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for your effort! I am still surprised because it works with the sans serif version of noto.